# How does performing LDA on the prediction from Linear Regression (OLS) give the same result as performing LDA on the predictors?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, discriminant-analysis

Suppose we transform the original predictors X to Yhat via linear
regression.

In detail, let Yhat = X(X'X)^(−1)X'Y = XBhat, where Y is the
indicator response matrix.

Similarly for any input x ∈ R^k, we get a transformed
vector Yhat = Bhat'x.

How can I show that LDA using Yhat is identical to
LDA in the original space.

Comment: what's LDA here? the term is ambiguous

Comment: least discriminant analysis